# How to derive a new base file name in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, filepath

What is the best/most standard way to rename just the base file name of a given file path in Qt, while preserving the directory and extension?

Is there a standard way to do that, or do I just use regular expressions?

Let's say I have:

```
/home/user/myfile.png
```

And it would be changed to:

```
/home/user/myfile-modified.png
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) to parse out the aspects of the path.

```
QFileInfo original("/home/user/myfile.png");
QString newPath = original.canonicalPath() + QDir::separator() + original.baseName() + "-modified";
if (!original.completeSuffix().isEmpty())
    newPath += "." + original.completeSuffix();
```

Warning: If your filename ends with a '.', but doesn't have an extension, this will drop the '.'. In other words, `/home/user/myfile.` will be renamed to `/home/user/myfile-modified`. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: Actually I don't want to move the file itself, I just want to derive a new name - for example, my program loads the original, makes modifications, and saves a new file based on the original's filename, but with '-modified' appended. So `QFile::rename` is not needed here.

Comment: You misunderstand. The original location is preserved using QFileInfo::canonicalPath() and is required for the file system to find the file location you are attempting to edit. QFile::rename() can't move files anyway.

Comment: I would add a line of code to verify whether the renaming was successful. QFile::rename will fail if the modified file name already exists.

Comment: @Phlucious That's not true. Here `QFile::rename()` eventually calls `rename()` which is actually able to rename _and_ move files. For example `QFile::rename("myFile", "../myFile")` will move _myFile_ to the parent directory.

Comment: @scai Interesting. I just ran a quick test and verified that you are correct. Not even 9:00am and I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

not tested, but this might work:

```
const char* filePath = "/home/user/myfile.png";
QFileInfo file(filePath);
QDir dir = file.dir();
QString baseName = file.baseName();
QString baseNameModified = ...; // insert here your logic for modifying filename
QFileInfo fileModified(dir, baseNameModified);
QString filePathModified = fileModified.filePath();
```